# Trying to use ctime to calculate the running time of a function

Tags: c++

I'm doing an assignment for a CS class, and part of the assignment is using ctime's clock() function to calculate the amount of time a sorting function takes. The code that does this is given to me, but it doesn't seem to work, since the output for elapsedTime is always 0. Here is the given code for this: 
    `const int CLOCKS_PER_MS = CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000; //clock per milliseconds
    ...
    clock_t Start = clock();
    //call sort function here
    clock_t End = clock();
    int elapsedTime = (End - Start)/CLOCKS_PER_MS; //converts elapsed time from 
    microseconds to milliseconds.`

Comment: System clocks typically tick in fairly beefy chunks, every 100 milliseconds is common, IIRC. As such, unless the function in question takes a significant fraction of a second to run, the system clock won't event tick, and same same value for clock() comes back before and after.

Comment: Might I suggest [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono). As your instructor if you can extricate yourself from the stone age and use something more modern.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The assignment has us sorting 3 arrays each of size 50000, so I believe it should take a measurable amount of time

Comment: That's a very small array for modern multi-GhZ CPUs.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I bumped up the array size and saw it working. Thanks for the help!